# DataOutputStream is not working the second time

Tags: java, sockets, dataoutputstream

I wan to write a message to a server. The first time I send a message everything works fine. But the second time I want to send another command the `dos.writeUTF(message);` line is throwing the NullPointerException. I really don't know why.

`GUICLIENT_INSTANCE` is for my Swing class

This is my initialize method:

```
private void initialize() {
        if (name != null && ip != null && port != 0) {
            String verify = "/v/" + name + "/" + ip + "/" + port + "/e/";
            boolean connect = openConnection(ip, port);
            if (connect) {
                send(verify);

                String receiveMsg = "";
                String[] temp = {};

                try {
                    try {
                        if (dis.available() > 0) {
                            receiveMsg = dis.readUTF();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println(receiveMsg);
                    temp = splitMsg(receiveMsg, "/");

                    if (receiveMsg.startsWith("/er/")) {
                        if (temp[2].equals("disconnected")) {
                            s.close();
                            GUICLIENT_INSTANCE.connectFail();
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Showing connected");
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Connected!");
                            GUICLIENT_INSTANCE.connected();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    GUICLIENT_INSTANCE.connectFail();
                }

                System.out.println(receiveMsg);

            } else {
                System.err.println("No server found with Address: " + ip + ":" + port);
                GUICLIENT_INSTANCE.connectFail();
            }
        }

    }
```

I open my connection with:

```
private boolean openConnection(String Sip, int port) {
        try {
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(Sip);
            s = new Socket(ip, port);
            dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This is the code of my send method:

```
public void send(String message) {
        try {
            if (s.isConnected()) {
                
                dos.writeUTF(message);

            } else {
                System.err.println("Failed sending! No connection!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: either `dos` or `message` is `null`, probably the first - stack trace probably had details to help finding out more - posted code does not help in finding out why either is `null`

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please add the entire stack trace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public void send(String message) {
    if (message == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null message not allowed");
    }
    if (dos == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("output stream is null");  
        // or new IOException
    }
    ...
```